# Using Where clause in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, where-clause

I'm new in ASP.NET.
Let say that I have a table called tblEmployees as follows

```
Id  Name        DeartmentId
1   Sara        1
2   John        1
3   Alex        2
4   Yank        3
5   Mike        4
6   Foster      2
```

Now I create a list called Department List.

```
List<int> DepartmentList = new List<int>();
```

Let’s add two values in this list.

```
DepartmentList.Add(2);
DepartmentList.Add(3)
```

Let’s get data from Sql

```
Var applicationDbContext = _context. tblEmployees;
```

Problem: Now I need to add a where clause and get result for applicationDbContext where DepartmentId is in the DepartmentList. In this case employees with Id# 3, 4 and 6 should come to the list.

```
var applicationDbContext2 = applicationDbContext.Where(t => t.DepartmentId in DepartmentList);
```

but the final view of the applicationDbContext2 has no any data.

Comment: It could be useful to read about [the proper usage of _in_ keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in).

Comment: Does it even compile with `.Where(t => t.DepartmentId in DepartmentList)`?

Comment: There is no way it does.

Comment: I thought so, which is why I wonder how OP got his result of "but the final view of the applicationDbContext2 has no any data" - either his code with "`in`" magically compiles, or he gave us different code than he actually ran...

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is done via `Contains`:

```
var filtered = _context. tblEmployees
    .Where(t => DepartmentList.Contains(t.DepartmentId))
    .ToList();
```